# Como cambiar el tamaño con .resize

Tags: jquery, html5, ajax, css3

Quiero cambiar el tamaño de mi caja en mi servidor ISS. Este es el código utilizado. Al hacer click en el botón Cambiar Tamaño no sucede nada.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Tema 2, Modulo 10</title>
    <style>
        .caja{
            border: 2px solid black;
            width: 200px;
            height: 100px;
        }
        .negrita{
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function tamaño(){
        var $divHeight = $('#micaja').height();
        if($divHeight => 100){
            $('div.caja').css({
                height:'50px'
            });
        }
        var $divWidth = $('#micaja').width();
        if($divWidth => 200){
            $('div.caja').css({
                width:'100px'
            });    
        }
        }
        console.log(($('.caja').height).value)
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="micaja" class="caja">Caja 1</div>

<button onclick="$('#micaja').hide()">Esconder</button>
<button onclick="$('#micaja').show()">Mostrar</button>
<button onclick="$('#micaja').fadeOut()">Desvanecer</button>
<button onclick="$('#micaja').fadeIn()">Resurgir</button>
<button onclick="$('#micaja').addClass('negrita')">Poner en negritra</button>
<button onclick="$('#micaja').resize(function(){ tamaño();})">Cambiar Tamaño</button>
<button onclick=""></button>
<button onclick=""></button>
<button onclick=""></button>

</body>
</html>
```

Llevo varios sitios visitados de como trabajar con la función resize y en muy pocos hay cantidad de información. No sé si la he liado en onclick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Teóricamente estas llamando a una función que se llama tamaño (Ojo con las ñ no son recomendadas en nombres de funciones y/o variables por el la decodificación)

Entonces lo que tendrías que hacer es solo llamar a la función cuando hagan click;

```
<button onclick="tamaño();">Cambiar Tamaño</button>
```

Espero haberte ayudado